# I am trying to convert a row of data from a dataframe into a numpy array. How can I do this?

Tags: arrays, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that contains multiple columns and rows.

Below is just one row of my dataframe, where the first columns are the headers and the second column is the data.

I used full_df.iloc[0] to extract the first row of data.

full_df is the name of my pandas dataframe.

```
  year      2015.0
  month        1.0
  day          1.0
  hour         0.0
  minute       0.0
  WDIR        13.0
  WSPD         5.6
  GST          6.9
  WVHT        99.0
  DPD         99.0
  APD         99.0
  MWD        999.0
  PRES      1026.1
  ATMP        11.4
  WTMP        17.8
  DEWP       999.0
  VIS         99.0
  TIDE        99.0
  Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

How can I get this data into a numpy array?

I tried doing the following:

```
   gfg = pd.Series(full_df.iloc[0])
   gfg.to_numpy
```

But I get the following error:

```
   AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'
```

Comment: What version of pandas do you use? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html#pandas.Series.to_numpy was added in version 0.24.0. If you use an older version you can either update your pandas version or use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can just try:

```py
import numpy as np
gfg = pd.Series(full_df.iloc[0])
np.array(gfg)
```

Is it what you want?

Comment: Hi yganalyst! Yes, that actually worked well. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Please select my answer.